# How to retreive status:checkbox from local storage alongside textcontent

Tags: javascript, html, css

i threw a little party in my home officie after i got my todo list to get data from local storage on page load and display it on the page.

I added a bit of the code to show how i save the todo list in local storage, and subsequently get it back.

i have one remaining problem however, one that i am not sure how to solve.
as you can see in my css, i have a status toggle, that can be checked on or off to denote completion of a task.

when the page reloads , the toggle status isn't saved.I think i should somehow add this status to the localstorage array alongside the todo text and then making a if contains() function to change classes to checked/unchecked. but maybe this isn't the best way to do it?

thanks for taking a look in any case!

```js
function localStorageUpdater() {

    let taskForStorage = document.querySelectorAll('.task-text');

    const localStorageArray: any = []
    for (let task of taskForStorage) {
        localStorageArray.push(task.textContent)
    }
    localStorage.setItem('localList',
        JSON.stringify(localStorageArray));
}

//parsedList

// @ts-ignore
const parsedList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localList'));
console.log(parsedList[2])

window.onload = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < parsedList.length; i++) {
        const parsedListCopy = listItemCreator(parsedList[i]);
        todoListElement?.appendChild(parsedListCopy);

        updateTheListoCounter();
    }
};
```

```css
.status-toggle {
    width: 1.3rem;
    height: 1.3rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    appearance: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 0.3rem;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.status-toggle:checked {
    background-color: #b3cbb2;
}

.status-toggle:checked + .task-text {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: #b6adad;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>To do list</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="/images/favicon-pineapple.jpg">
</head>
<body>


<h1 class="title">todos</h1>
<form id="todo-form" onsubmit="todoListCreator()">
    <input type="radio"  id="scrolldown-menu-toggle" >
    <input type="text" id="todo-input" placeholder="Fill in your plan">
</form>

<template id="list-item-template">
    <li class="list-item">
        <input type="checkbox" class="status-toggle" name="form-checkbox">
        <span class="task-text"></span>
        <button class="delete">X</button>
    </li>

</template>

<ol id="ordered-todo-list">
</ol>


<span id="listo"></span>




<footer class="info">
    <p>Double click to edit a todo.</p>
    <p>Created by Thomas Brom.</p>
</footer>


<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you store the list of todos? Is it an array of objects?

Comment: it is simply and array. i first save an empty array into a constant, then loop over the todo list, and push the text content there for every loop. I then make a key for the localstorage, and save the array as the value.

Comment: You can store an array of objects instead of a text array. Each object will have properties like `id`, `title`, and a boolean flag `isComplete`. You can toggle the boolean flag when that todo is complete.

Comment: the question is, how do i do this with user input. i know how to make on in a static enviroment. but making something like  const objectForInput =[ {input text: toggle status }] and then getting it onto the page, is giving me headaches. especially because i am looping over the array/object tring to insert it one by one